# Periodically calling TinyMCE's triggerSave function

Tags: tinymce

If anyone knows TinyMCE well, do you know if it has built-in support for periodically calling its triggerSave function?

(This function copies it's content to its "parent" textarea. I want to observe said textarea for changes so I can implement autosave.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't try autosave, trust me on this one.  triggerSave is buggy and when it fails it fails silently so you think that your content got posted, but in reality it didn't.  After it fails once it will no longer work for the rest of the session, as in until the page is manually reloaded and tinymce does another full init().

Just got bit by this one badly, again.  Never again trust triggerSave.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still true of `triggerSave()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this yourself by using JavaScript's setTimeout() function.

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp.

Comment: This is what I've done actually - I was just wondering if TinyMCE had something built in.
Thanks